# How do I create a loop in a function to get a cin that is both a number and in a certain range, to return the value?

Tags: c++, member-functions

Hi I need to create an int member function within a class that needs to display a menu and then prompts the user for a cin input that is both a number and between 1-5. It needs to loop the cin until a correct value is given displaying a different error message depending on the issue It then needs to be able to return that value.

Here is my code in c++

```
int ClassName::menu() {
        cout << "Menu title" << endl;
        cout << "1- option1" << endl;
        cout << "2- op 2" << endl;
        cout << "3- op 3" << endl;
        cout << "4- op 4" << endl;
        cout << "5- op 5" << endl;
        cout << "0- exit program" << endl;
        cout << "> ";
        int flag = 1;
        int value;
        string input;
        while (flag == 1) {
            getline(cin, input);
            value = stoi(input);
            if (input[0] < '0' || input[0] > '5') {
                cout << "Invalid Integer, try again: ";
                input.clear();
            }
            else if (value < 0 || value > 5) {
                    cout << "[0<=value<=5], retry: ";
                    input.clear();
            }
            else {
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? As far as I can tell, your program will just crash on non-integer input, unless you are handling exceptions outside this code. Note that `std::stoi` will throw if conversion fails. So you should wrap that in a try-catch and forget about the first if-statement where you're checking characters in `input`.

Comment: I can't use try, and I don't want my program to crash. what should I do then? do I have to move stoi?

Comment: Why can't you use `try`? It's a C++ feature since forever. Anyway, you can use [std::strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) instead, and perform additional validation such as ensuring the remainder of the unparsed string is empty or whitespace, and that the return value didn't have a range error as per the documentation. Or you can do all your integer validation by hand before calling `std::stoi`, provided you capture everything that might cause it to throw.

Comment: @Stevelel "*what should I do then? do I have to move stoi?*" - no, you should stop using `stoi` in the first place, it is the wrong tool for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

`stoi()` throws an exception if the conversion fails, but you are not catching the exception.

After you have successfully converted the input string into an integer, there is no need to look at the individual characters of the input, especially since you are not even looking at the whole input.

But really, why are you reading the input into a string and then converting it into an integer in the first place? You should use `operator>>` instead to read the input into the integer directly.

Also, you are not using `cin.clear()` correctly. It does not remove data from the input buffer. It resets the stream's error state, but you are calling it in a spot where the stream is not in an error state.

Try this instead:

```
int ClassName::menu() {
    cout << "Menu title" << endl;
    cout << "1- option1" << endl;
    cout << "2- op 2" << endl;
    cout << "3- op 3" << endl;
    cout << "4- op 4" << endl;
    cout << "5- op 5" << endl;
    cout << "0- exit program" << endl;
    cout << "> ";

    int value;
    do {
        if (cin >> value) {
            if (value >= 0 && value <= 5) {
                break;
            }
            cout << "Invalid choice, retry: "; 
        }
        else {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Invalid input, retry: ";
        }
    }
    while (true);

    return value;
}
```